# flutter can't recognize android studio even after defining android-studio-dir (linux)

Tags: linux, flutter, android-studio

when i run

`flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Linux, locale C)
    • Flutter version 2.0.5 at /home/mohamed/DevelopmentKit/flutter
    • Framework revision adc687823a (9 days ago), 2021-04-16 09:40:20 -0700
    • Engine revision b09f014e96
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/mohamed/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/mohamed/DevelopmentKit/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    ✗ Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at ~/DevelopmentKit/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ android-studio-dir = ~/DevelopmentKit/android-studio
    ✗ Android Studio not found at ~/DevelopmentKit/android-studio
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
    • Consider removing your android-studio-dir setting by running:
      flutter config --android-studio-dir=

[!] Connected device
    ! Device 5203ff72fa4514a5 is not authorized.
      You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

it doesn't detect it while my directory contains android-studio installation

`ls -la ~/DevelopmentKit/android-studio`

```
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  7 mohamed users  4096 Mar 11 01:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 mohamed users  4096 Apr 26 01:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 mohamed users  1840 Mar 11 01:14 Install-Linux-tar.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mohamed users 11352 Mar 11 01:14 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mohamed users   396 Mar 11 01:14 NOTICE.txt
drwxr-xr-x  4 mohamed users  4096 Mar 11 01:53 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 mohamed users    25 Mar 11 01:14 build.txt
drwxr-xr-x  6 mohamed users  4096 Mar 11 01:53 jre
drwxr-xr-x  5 mohamed users 16384 Mar 11 01:53 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 mohamed users  4096 Mar 11 01:53 license
drwxr-xr-x 52 mohamed users  4096 Mar 11 01:53 plugins
-rw-r--r--  1 mohamed users   383 Mar 11 01:14 product-info.json
```

i have tried:
-adding the android-studio/bin to PATH
-adding android-studio-dir="~/DevelopmentKit/android-studio" (with and without quotes)
-rebooting

Comment: What would "Android licenses not accepted." mean?

Comment: @Roadowl I don't know, but I am pretty sure its not the problem